# Sort a Spark data frame/ Hive result set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to retrieve the list of columns from a Hive table and store the result in a spark dataframe.

```
var my_column_list = hiveContext.sql(s""" SHOW COLUMNS IN $my_hive_table""")
```

But I'm unable to alphabetically sort the dataframe or even the result of the show columns query. I tried using sort and orderBy().

How could I sort the result alphabetically?

**Update:** Added a sample of my code

```
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.sql("USE my_test_db")

var lv_column_list = hiveContext.sql(s""" SHOW COLUMNS IN MYTABLE""")
//WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems

lv_column_list.show //Works fine
lv_column_list.orderBy("result").show //Error arises
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'SHOW COLUMNS', I used 'DESC' and retrieved the column list with "col_name".

```
var lv_column_list = hiveContext.sql(s""" DESC MYTABLE""")
lv_column_list.select("col_name").orderBy("col_name")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SHOW COLUMNS` query produces a Dataframe with a column named `result`. If you order by this column, you get what you want :

```
val df = hiveContext.sql(s""" SHOW COLUMNS IN $my_hive_table """)
df.orderBy("result").show
```

Comment: I got an exception "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) result#31 missing from result#21 in operator !Sort [result#31 ASC], true;"

Comment: Added a code snippet in the question. When I execute the show columns part, I get a warning (shown in the code). Could this be a possible reason for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are using the sort or orderBy method,

Try the following,

```
df.sort(asc("column_name"))    
df.orderBy(asc("column_name"))
```

Comment: The sorting is not the problem here, it is related to the result of the `show columns` command.